# sumar los maximos de una tabla

Tags: php

tengo una tabla donde cargo "actividades" para cada "ciclista" por "semana" necesito obtener la actividad mas larga de cada ciclista en cada semana y luego sumar dichas actividades, no estoy pudiendo hacerlo con subconsultas y no termino de entender como si se puede con una tabla temporal...
esta es la tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la consulta que realizo es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en esa consulta logro obtener las actividades mas largas, pero no puedo sumarlas despues!

me pueden dar una mano de como obtenerlo?
necesito que el resultado sea para cada ciclista la suma de las distancias mas largas de cada etapa

muchas gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Que tiene que ver php aca? sera mysql? y si haces sum en lugar de max y sacas la etapa? Mostra cual es el resultado que queres obtener...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si ya obtienes los máximos de cada ciclista bastaría con sumar esos máximos, lo cual puedes hacer con una subconsulta, esto debería funcionar:

```sql
SELECT 
    t.nombre, t.etapa, SUM(t.maxdistancia)
FROM
    (SELECT 
        nombre, etapa, MAX(distancia) AS maxdistancia
    FROM
        ciclista, actividad
    WHERE
        ciclista.idciclista = actividad.ciclistaid
    GROUP BY nombre , actividad.etapa) t
GROUP BY t.nombre
ORDER BY t.maxdistancia DESC;
```

Comment: MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'LIMIT 0, 25' en la linea 11...

me sale eso cuando ejecuto la consulta..

Comment: Listo, ha sido error mío al colocar el último `ORDER BY`, ya no debería salir el error.

Comment: le saco el ORDER o lo pongo fuera de los parentesis, y sigue con el mismo error

Comment: MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'LIMIT 0, 25' en la linea 10

Comment: Que me he olvidado de colocar el alias para el subquery.

Comment: me da un unico resultado, digamos, me suma todos los maxdistancia pero saca un unico registro de resultado, no por cada ciclista. EJ:nombre
etapa
SUM(t.maxdistancia)
Agus Torres
1
5165.89

Comment: Agrega un `GROUP BY t.nombre`, aunque lo ideal sería que tuvieras un `id` y hacer la agrupación en relación a ese id.

Comment: Gracias!!! asi me funcionooo

Comment: Por nada, no olvides seguir las recomendaciones que te han hecho sobre la pregunta. El código en imagen no es bien recibido así que tenlo en cuenta para la próxima vez. Tampoco olvides marcar la respuesta si ha resuelto tu problema.